# Overflow dots not appearing on tablet

Tags: android, android-actionbar

For some reason the overflow dots do not appear on my tablet for my master detail application when I select a list item but yet they do on my handset. I'm not sure why is occurring despite using the necessary code. Does anyone there is any code missing or that shouldn't be there?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private boolean mTwoPane;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if (menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.greeting));

        FragmentMainList newFragment = new FragmentMainList();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.master_container, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();

        if (findViewById(R.id.detail_container) != null) {
            mTwoPane = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity Class**

```
public class MyProductActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_fragment);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentProduct newFragment = new FragmentProduct();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            final Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Fragment Class**

```
public class FragmentProduct extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    public FragmentProduct() {}

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = getView();

        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            final Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(getActivity());
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(getActivity(), intent);
            return true;
        }

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_options) {
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your tablet has menu key ?

Comment: The Overflow dots only show up when you have more items on your action bar than can be shown at one time.  You have more space on the tablet

Comment: @jradich1234 Is there any way of showing them regardless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dots will be shown only for devices which don't have hardware Menu button. For devices with a hardware Menu button no overflow dots are shown since tapping on the menu button will do the same. 
For more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

**Edit**

If for some reason you really want to show it, you can add below code in your `Application.onCreate()` or main (launcher) activity `onCreate()`

```
// force show actionbar 'overflow' button on devices with hardware menu button
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if (menuKeyField != null) {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Where is `Application.onCreate()`?

Comment: Your `Application` file if you have such added. If not, add it in your launcher activity `onCreate()` but before calling `setContentView()`

Comment: Hmmmm still not appearing for some reason. MainActivity code is now in my post.

Comment: `WCBankActivity` is your main activity right? So paste the code in its `onCreate()` method. I see it here working properly in Note 4 (since it has a menu button). If your tablet does **not** have a hardware Menu button and still not seeing the overflow menu - then it is a different case. What manufacturer, brand is the tablet?

Comment: I'm using a tablet emulator as I don't have a real tablet. I think it's best to not to show it and depend on user clicking the menu button on their tablet. Either way I'll still accept your answer.

Comment: OK, Booted GenyMotion with 2 simulated devices with hardware buttons - Note 3 and XPeria Tablet Z. Both have hardware buttons - both show the overflow menu even so. If you are using Android emulator, maybe you would want to try and stick with [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/). It is free same as the emulator.

Comment: What about using this for fragments? Remember on tablets, I'm using the master detail hence I'm replacing the detail pane with fragments rather than activities. How can I use that code for my fragment rather than the activity? I want to show different overflow menus based on the fragment that was replaced.

Comment: Well, it does not matter if you are using activities or fragments. You are using at least one activity (your launcher activity). Add the code in your launcher activity.

Comment: Okay cool. Do you know how to solve this? [Fast scroll large letter thumb preview not appearing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321784/fast-scroll-large-letter-thumb-preview-not-appearing)